# How to clear all formatting from body text in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I didn't find this question anywhere, so I don't if it's even possible because we can't record macro in Outlook.

But, I'd like to clear all text formatting in my e-mail that I'm replying by a macro in Outlook.

Since I'm using `olReply.HTMLBody` and building all the body with a `Loop` and some `if` and `elses`, I couldn't format the body in it.

Example:
[Clear all text formatting - Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/clear-all-text-formatting-c094c4da-7f09-4cea-9a8d-c166949c9c80?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not sure how your code looks like but here is quick example using **[ClearFormatting Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171844(v=office.11))** Make sure you click  Reply or ReplyAll and select the text you are trying to format then run the code*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Exmple()
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim rngSel As Word.selection

    If Application.ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
        Set wDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor ' use WordEditor
        Set rngSel = wDoc.Windows(1).selection ' Current selection

        rngSel.ClearFormatting

    End If

    Set wDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, it worked like a charm! Thank you very much @0m3r. I also added the **MS Word Reference** in my Oulook (Do this from Tools | References, then add reference to MS Word.), and called the macro after displaying (`.display`) the e-mail.

Comment: if I use this code, the e-mail doesn't send, do you know why? I'm using reply.

Comment: I solved the formatting using this solution. [Format HTML Body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2597786/10176057)